# How to pass an object method inside a Ruby block as an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order to avoid repetition I have this presenter method to generate social links of a company page:

```
  def social
    networks = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter']
    networks.each do |network|
      h.concat h.link_to h.image_tag("icons/#{network}.png"), @company.network, target: '_blank' unless @company.network.blank?
    end
  end
```

However the block argument acts as an object method, and I don't want that. How would I pass actual array values to the object here? I am currently getting the 'undefined method Network for obj Company...'

Update:

Given that only Facebook and Twitter fields are filled, I would like my outupd to be:

```
<a href="link to facebook"><img src='icons/facebook.png'></a>
<a href="link to twitter"><img src='icons/twitter.png'></a>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean with "object method" and what you want to achieve? Maybe a bit of pseudo-code would be helpful. I am having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: updated with desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the value of the network variable to the object:

```
def social
  networks = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter']
  networks.each do |network|
    company_network = @company.send(network)
    h.concat h.link_to h.image_tag("icons/#{network}.png"), company_network, target: '_blank' unless company_network.blank?
  end
end
```

For this to work, your object @company needs to respond to the messages/methods facebook, instagram, youtube, twitter.

A better way would be to implement a networks method which returns a hash with the name of the available networks as key and their link as value:

```
class Company
  AVAILABLE_NETWORKS = %i(facebook instagram youtube twitter)
  attr_accessor AVAILABLE_NETWORKS

  def networks
    AVAILABLE_NETWORKS.each_with_object{|network|
      { network: send(network) }
    end.reject{|k,v| v.blank? }
  end

end
```

You should also write your helper method in a way that makes it independent of the context (reusable) by eliminating the dependency on the @company instance and replace it with a parameter. 
In the method itself you then just need to iterate over the hash to get the network names and links.

```
def social(company)
  company.networks.each do |name, link|
    h.concat h.link_to h.image_tag("icons/#{name}.png"), link, target: '_blank'
  end
end
```

Comment: Weird, it does not work.. I have facebook, etc. methods on my company objects (strings with urls), but this code is giving me undefined method `network' for #<Company:0x007ff5571ada20>

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited the code. send(:network) needs to be send(network).

Comment: I am glad this helped :) I added a bit more explanation.